# Filter function skips over November and December Date objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, filter

I'm using a filter function to remove the dates contained in one array, `excludedDates` from a second array, `saturdays`. Each array contains Date objects.

```
const newSaturdays = this.saturdays.filter(date => !excludedDates.find(ex => ex.getTime() === date.getTime()));
```

This function works perfectly well unless I try to exclude a date in November or December. It ignores any date in `excludedDates` that falls in November or December and leaves it in the `newSaturdays` array.

Can anybody suggest why this might be happening, and how I might fix it?

EDIT: Sample data:

```
saturdays = [new Date('2022-09-10'), new Date('2022-09-17'), new Date('2022-10-01'), new Date('2022-10-08'), new Date('2022-10-15'), new Date('2022-10-22'), new Date('2022-10-29'), new Date('2022-11-05'), new Date('2022-11-12'), new Date('2022-11-19'), new Date('2022-11-26'), new Date('2022-12-03'), new Date('2022-12-10'), new Date('2022-12-17')]

excludedDates = [new Date('2022-09-24'), new Date('2022-10-15'), new Date('2022-10-22'), new Date('2022-10-29'), new Date('2022-11-19'), new Date('2022-12-17').
```

EDIT: I found the solution. The time zone changes at the end of October, from British Summertime to UTC, which was throwing off the getTime() method. Using getDate() instead worked.

Comment: `excludedDates` should be a `Set` for `O(1)` lookup, whereas using `Array.prototype.find` is going to give you awful runtime complexity on the order of `O( n*m )`.

Comment: Please provide a better code sample: one that includes sample-data for those arrays.

Comment: It would also help if both arrays were sorted, then you could do a custom filter so that the search for each date to filter starts at the next index of the previous filtered element (assuming no duplicates).

Comment: Fair point, Dai, I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow and coding in general, but that would be useful. In the actual code they're generated by functions, but I'll edit some proper data into my post.
I have no clue what you mean by the first answer, but you've given me something to look up and figure out, so thank you.